# Load partial form on dropdownlist change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a dropdown list of License Plates where the last item is "New License Plate". By default, the form will not show the new License Plate form fields (text box for new license plate, and dropdown list of state/province origin of plate).

How would I show the form based on the selection of "New License Plate"?

I have created a partial view so far:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Namespace.ViewModels.ProfileMemberViewModel>" %>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="100%" border="0" align="left">
<tr>
    <td>
        <%=Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewLicensePlate.LicensePlate, new { @class = "inputLabel" })%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewLicensePlate.LicensePlate, new { @class = "inputField" })%>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%=Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewLicensePlate.PlateState, new { @class = "inputLabel" })%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NewLicensePlate.PlateState, Model.NewLicensePlate.PlateStates, new { @class = "inputField" })%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Parent form:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Paysite.Providers.ViewModels.ProfileMemberViewModel>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Confirm", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "Profile-form" }))
   {%>
...
<tr>
    <td>
        <%=Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member.LicensePlate, new { @class = "inputLabel" })%>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span class="small">(To add, select "New License Plate")</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Member.LicensePlate, Model.Member.LicensePlates, new { @class = "inputField" })%>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="NewLicensePlate">            
</div>
...
<%
   } %>
```

jQuery in parent form:

```
$("#Member_LicensePlate").change(function () {
  var selectedPlate = $("#Member_LicensePlate").val();
  if (selectedPlate == "New License Plate") {
    $("#NewLicensePlate").load('<%= Url.Action("NewLicensePlate") %>');
  } else {
    $('#NewLicensePlate').empty();
  }
});
```

ViewModels:

```
public class ProfileMemberViewModel
{
    public ExistingMemberViewModel Member { get; set; }
    public NewLicensePlateViewModel NewLicensePlate { get; set; }
}

public class NewLicensePlateViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "License Plate")]
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Province/State")]
    public string PlateState { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PlateStates { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult NewLicensePlate()
{
    var model = new ProfileMemberViewModel();
    model.NewLicensePlate = new NewLicensePlateViewModel();

    DataSet statesDataSet = _statesRepo.GetStates();

    model.NewLicensePlate.PlateStates =
            Enumerable.Select(statesDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Field<string>("NAME"),
            Value = x.Field<double>("ID").ToString()
        });

    return PartialView("NewLicensePlate", model);
}
```

When I post from the parent from to `public ActionResult Confirm(ProfileMemberViewModel model)`, `model.NewLicensePlate` does not get the bindings, it's `null`. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: luke, just to double check, the form tag does close AFTER the NewLicensePlate div?? Just that you don't show the form tag closure in your code

Comment: Yes, sorry it does, for brevity, left rest of form out but I'll put that in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to put all fields in tha same (parent form). Hide controls for new plates.
Using javascript you show them based on the selection of "New License Plate".
When the form is posted, you process the new license plate if controls are filled

Comment: Thanks, yah I was thinking of doing that, but wanted to try something new, but I may just keep it simple.